# Not able to redirect the page after the ajax success statuscode

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

```
 function postToGoogle() {


    var name = $('#name').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var college = $('#college').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var year = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs6']:checked").val();



    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/1/d/e/KEY/formResponse",
        data: {
            "entry.1735346271": name,
             "entry.393911750": phone,
              "entry.1827584616": email,
              "entry.1041274008": college,
              "entry.334726096":year 
            },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        statusCode: {
            0: function() {
                window.location.href("URL");
                // window.open("URL");
                alert("Thank you for sending us your details.");
            },
             200: function() {
                window.location.href("URL");
            //     window.open("URL");
               alert("Thank you for sending us your details.");
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Well am trying to send data into the google sheet through above function which I succeeded but I want after submitting the form when status code is O or 200 ,I want an alert box and the page is redirected to another page. While trying I was able to manage to show the alert box but not able to redirect the page.Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? If there are any, please include them in your question by editing

Comment: Yes, I do check there is nothing printing in the console.

Comment: I'm surprised, you should get something like “window.location.href” is not a function. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) incorrectly. It is not a function that you call, but rather a property that you change by assigning a new value.

Change the part of your code that does the redirect to this:

```
 window.location.href = "URL";
```

(I assume that `"URL"` in your example is actually a valid URL in your actual code).

You should also put the `alert` statement after the redirect statement, otherwise it won't be displayed because the page location has changed before that.